# Can we use gson model with realm? When I'm trying it's showing a build time error

Tags: android, gradle, realm, build.gradle

**When I'm try to build or run project at time showing me error, GSON model means Which I am going to use in webservice response and I'm using realm database FirstTime so**

**My Model Class**

*InstaSave.class*

```
    package model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import io.realm.RealmObject;

// I extend realm in my gson model 
public class InstaSave extends RealmObject {

    @SerializedName("provider_url")
    @Expose
    private String providerUrl;
    @SerializedName("media_id")
    @Expose
    private String mediaId;
    @SerializedName("author_name")
    @Expose
    private String authorName;
    @SerializedName("height")
    @Expose
    private Object height;
    @SerializedName("thumbnail_url")
    @Expose
    private String thumbnailUrl;
    @SerializedName("thumbnail_width")
    @Expose
    private Integer thumbnailWidth;
    @SerializedName("thumbnail_height")
    @Expose
    private Integer thumbnailHeight;
    @SerializedName("provider_name")
    @Expose
    private String providerName;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("html")
    @Expose
    private String html;
    @SerializedName("width")
    @Expose
    private Integer width;
    @SerializedName("version")
    @Expose
    private String version;
    @SerializedName("author_url")
    @Expose
    private String authorUrl;
    @SerializedName("author_id")
    @Expose
    private Double authorId;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The providerUrl
     */
    public String getProviderUrl() {
        return providerUrl;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param providerUrl
     *     The provider_url
     */
    public void setProviderUrl(String providerUrl) {
        this.providerUrl = providerUrl;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The mediaId
     */
    public String getMediaId() {
        return mediaId;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param mediaId
     *     The media_id
     */
    public void setMediaId(String mediaId) {
        this.mediaId = mediaId;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The authorName
     */
    public String getAuthorName() {
        return authorName;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param authorName
     *     The author_name
     */
    public void setAuthorName(String authorName) {
        this.authorName = authorName;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The height
     */
    public Object getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param height
     *     The height
     */
    public void setHeight(Object height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The thumbnailUrl
     */
    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param thumbnailUrl
     *     The thumbnail_url
     */
    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The thumbnailWidth
     */
    public Integer getThumbnailWidth() {
        return thumbnailWidth;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param thumbnailWidth
     *     The thumbnail_width
     */
    public void setThumbnailWidth(Integer thumbnailWidth) {
        this.thumbnailWidth = thumbnailWidth;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The thumbnailHeight
     */
    public Integer getThumbnailHeight() {
        return thumbnailHeight;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param thumbnailHeight
     *     The thumbnail_height
     */
    public void setThumbnailHeight(Integer thumbnailHeight) {
        this.thumbnailHeight = thumbnailHeight;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The providerName
     */
    public String getProviderName() {
        return providerName;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param providerName
     *     The provider_name
     */
    public void setProviderName(String providerName) {
        this.providerName = providerName;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The title
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param title
     *     The title
     */
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The html
     */
    public String getHtml() {
        return html;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param html
     *     The html
     */
    public void setHtml(String html) {
        this.html = html;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The width
     */
    public Integer getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param width
     *     The width
     */
    public void setWidth(Integer width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The version
     */
    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param version
     *     The version
     */
    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The authorUrl
     */
    public String getAuthorUrl() {
        return authorUrl;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param authorUrl
     *     The author_url
     */
    public void setAuthorUrl(String authorUrl) {
        this.authorUrl = authorUrl;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The authorId
     */
    public Double getAuthorId() {
        return authorId;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param authorId
     *     The author_id
     */
    public void setAuthorId(Double authorId) {
        this.authorId = authorId;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The type
     */
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param type
     *     The type
     */
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

**Error**

```
1) D:\Android_Studio_Task\InstaSave\app\src\main\java\model\InstaSave.java
   -Error:(10, 8) error: Type java.lang.Object of field height is not supported

2) Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Realm cannot serialize an `Object` (height attribute). It has to be a primitive type. Looking at your code, you might want to use `Integer` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error states, that you cannot have an Object type as a field

Quoted from https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#field-types :

> Realm supports the following field types: boolean, byte, short, int, long, float, double, String, Date and byte[]. The integer types byte, short, int, and long are all mapped to the same type (long actually) within Realm. Moreover, subclasses of RealmObject and RealmList<? extends RealmObject> are supported to model relationships.

> The boxed types Boolean, Byte, Short, Integer, Long, Float and Double can also be used in model classes. Using these types, it is possible to set the value of a field to null.

You need to declare the field as one of these types, however if you can serialize/deserialize a type that is not allowed using permitted ones, then you can do this in getters/setters and expose an API with desired object type to the user.

You can also use @Ignore annotation, so that this particular field is not taken into an account and you can populate it yourself upon object creation, but it is a far less secure way as you need to keep in mind this fact every time you work with it.

Answer (score 1):

you might need to create separate class for serialized models and realm models, and then map them.